# What's the proper way to do a FormGroup with FormBuilder in Typescript 4.7+?

Tags: angular, typescript

In the past we'd do this:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  nameForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.createForm();
  }

  createForm() {
    this.nameForm = this.fb.group({
      surname: '',
      first_name: ''
    });
  }
}
```

But in TypeScript 4.7+ you get this error:

```
error TS2564: Property 'nameForm' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor.
```

I could disable "strictpropertyinitilization" in tsconfig.json, or I could declare nameForm as FormGroup | undefined. Neither of those are good options. I could put the formbuilder in the constructor, but we're not supposed to put that stuff in constructors.

So what's the proper Angular Typescript way to do this going forward?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Angular documentation](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms), the correct way of creating a FormGroup is by doing this:

```js
export class ProfileEditorComponent {
  profileForm = new FormGroup({
    firstName: new FormControl(''),
    lastName: new FormControl(''),
  });
}
```

If you want to use a formBuilder, you need to declare your formGroup like this:

```js
nameForm!: FormGroup;
```

or:

```js
export class AppComponent { 
   title = 'app'; 
   exampleForm = new FormGroup ({ firstName: new FormControl(), lastName: new FormControl()});

   constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
     this.createForm();
   }

   createForm() {
     this.exampleForm = this.formBuilder.group({
       firstName: '',
       lastName: ''
     });
   }
}
```

Comment: But isn't that just circumventing the check, rather than properly complying with the rule?

Comment: You're probably right, I updated my answer to match the Angular documentation.

Comment: So then that means we can't use FormBuilder?

Answer (score 1):

I think we can use something like this to solve the problem.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  nameForm!: FormGroup;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.createForm();
  }

  createForm() {
    this.nameForm = this.fb.group({
      surname: [''],
      first_name: ['']
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest way is to do it during property initialization:

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  /* at this point `fb` is already injected and can be used */
  nameForm = this.fb.group({
    surname: '',
    first_name: ''
  });

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {}
}
```

Other options that you have:

```
/* just suppress the TS validation with `!` because you know that it's can not be undefined */
nameForm!: FormGroup;

/* make it explicit FormGroup or undefined */
nameForm: FormGroup | undefined;

/* do set up in constructor, then TS will not throw an error */
constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
  nameForm = this.fb.group({
    surname: '',
    first_name: ''
  });
}
```

Comment: This looks also interesting: https://www.techiediaries.com/angular-formbuilder-formgroup/ (Step 4)